# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool while connecting to redis cluster

Tags: java, docker, redis

I am trying to connect to redis cluster using java **JedisCluster** client .

First I made Redis Cluster using this docker image

[grokzen/redis-cluster](https://hub.docker.com/r/grokzen/redis-cluster/)

Created 6 nodes (3 masters && 3 slaves)

Using docker machine in windows I started redis cluster using this command

```
docker run -p 7000:7000 -p 7001:7001 -p 7002:7002 -p 7003:7003 -p 7004:7004 -p 7005:7005 -p 7006:7006 -p 7007:7007 dockerImageId
```

**Redis Cluster starting short Log :**

> > Using 3 masters:
> >
> > 172.17.0.2:7000
> >
> > 172.17.0.2:7001
> >
> > 172.17.0.2:7002
>
> Adding replica 172.17.0.2:7004 to 172.17.0.2:7000 Adding replica
>   172.17.0.2:7005
>
> to 172.17.0.2:7001 Adding replica
>
> > 172.17.0.2:7003 to 172.17.0.2:7002

**Java Client for Redis Cluster:**

```
Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("192.168.99.100", 7000));
        JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);
        jc.set("key", "Redis-Val");
        String value = jc.get("key");
        System.out.println("key is : "+value);
```

After running this code I got this Exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
>   a resource from the pool  at
>   redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:66)
>     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:116)
>     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
>     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
>     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
>     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
>     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:31)
>     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.set(JedisCluster.java:103)  at
>   redis.redis_example.App.main(App.java:20) Caused by:
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

I have checked that redis is running on any node in the cluster by telnet command :

> telnet 192.168.99.100 7000

connected successfully

Comment: Could you try to connect to your `localhost:7000` instead of `192.168.99.100:7000` ? Or do a `docker inspect`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the IP env variable when running the container:

```
docker run -d -p 7000-7005:7000-7005 -e "IP=0.0.0.0" grokzen/redis-cluster:latest
```